# How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert null to int

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a music bot using discord.js which will let me play music when I provide a URL. The entirety of my code is given below. When I try to execute the play command it returns a `TypeError`.

```js
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const bot = new Discord.Client;
    const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
    const token = '';

    const prefix = '!';
    var servers = {};

    bot.on('ready', () =>{
        console.log('This bot is online');
    })
    bot.on('message', message=>{

        let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");


        switch(args[0]){
            case 'play':

                function play(connection,message){
                    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                    server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

                    server.queue.shift();

                    server.dispatcher.on("speaking", function(){
                        if(server.queue[0]){
                            play(connection, message);
                        }
                        else{
                            connection.disconnect();
                        }
                    });

                }

                if(!args[1]){
                    message.channel.send('give link');
                    return;
                }

                if(!message.member.voice.channel){
                    message.channel.send('user must be in vc');
                    return;
                }

                if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] ={
                    queue: []
                }

                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.queue.push(args[1]);

                if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                    play(connection, message);
                })

            break;

        };

    });

    bot.login(token);
```

It connects to the voice channel but doesn't play anything and returns this error:
`TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int`

Comment: At which place & code exactly the error is happening?

Comment: that's the thing the terminal doesn't specify exactly where the error is happening

Comment: You mean its only showing error message and no error stack trace at all?

Comment: never mind...solved it. just had to install a dependency: npm install discord.js ffmpeg fluent-ffmpeg @discordjs/opus ytdl-core --save